# Put the checkbox on the right side of the label

Tags: html, checkbox

I want to design a series of horizontal checkboxes where the checkboxes are located on the right side of the labels.

This is what I have written where the labels are located on the left side.

```css
.add-margin {
  margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div ng-init="loaded()" ng-class="{'add-margin': descriptionsAvailable}" class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="opt in options track by $index">
    <label>
      <input ng-disabled="answer['none']" type="checkbox" ng-model="answer[opt]" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" name="checkbox-answer-input" display= inline-block >
      <span>{{opt}}</span><br/>
      <span><i>{{descriptions[$index]}}</i></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you can create a stackblitz, I might be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the code like this

```
<div>
  <div ng-init="loaded()" ng-class="{'add-margin': descriptionsAvailable}" class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="opt in options track by $index">
    <label>
<span>{{opt}}</span>
      <input ng-disabled="answer['none']" type="checkbox" ng-model="answer[opt]" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" name="checkbox-answer-input" display= inline-block >
      <br/>
      <span><i>{{descriptions[$index]}}</i></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the checkbox on left and the  text on right with `opt` and `description` on separate rows.
You need to add some styles like following and provide relevant classes. I hope this helps.

HTML

```
<div>
  <div ng-init="loaded()" ng-class="{'add-margin': descriptionsAvailable}" class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="opt in options track by $index">
    <label class="container">
      <input ng-disabled="answer['none']" type="checkbox" ng-model="answer[opt]" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" name="checkbox-answer-input" display= inline-block >
      <div class="description">
       <span>{{opt}}</span><br/>
       <span><i>{{descriptions[$index]}}</i></span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.add-margin {
  margin-top: 10px !important;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.description {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how I assume you want the data to show up. If you require a different layout, then let me know

[image: Here is a screenshot of how I assume you want the data to show up]

Comment: The checkboxes are already on the left. I want them to be on the right.

Comment: @BNoor then you need to provide `flex-direction: row-reverse;` I have updated my answer.